# Combinatorial problem, count how many numbers less than $10^{10}$ have increasing digits?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the problem :

Pak Dengklek is very fond of fiddling with numbers and gives a name for the unique nature of a number. One of the unique characteristics of the numbers by Mr. Dengklek is uphill numbers. A number $X$ is called an Increase Number when the digits of $X$ rise from left to right. Example 
The uphill number is $122349$. Suddenly Mr. Dengklek is curious, how many uphill numbers are worth less than ($10^{10}$)?

Someone solved this problem by using hockey stick identity, but I don't understand the way he solved it. Could there be another way to solve this problem  simply?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - It's a shame when interesting questions get closed for this reason. I don't really see the benefit.

Comment: Are the numbers in question positive or nonnegative?

Comment: Related: [Number of non-decreasing functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396896/number-of-non-decreasing-functions).

Answer (score 2):

Write a binary word consisting of $10$ ixes and $9$ separating bars, like so:
$$x\ |\ x\ x\ |\ |\ x\ x\ |\ |\ |\ x\ x\ x\ |\ x\ |\ x\ |\ \quad.$$
Now count along this word, starting with $0$. For each separating bar count $1$ ahead, and for each $x$ write down the momentary number. In this way you get a typical "Increase Number". In the above example this is the number
$$0\ 1\ 1\ 3\ 3\ 6\ 6\ 6\ 7\ 8$$

It becomes apparent that each such word determines exactly one "Increase Number", and conversely: Each "Increase Number" determines exactly one such code word.

It follows that the number of "Increase Numbers" is ${19\choose9}=92\,378$. As $9$ is not far away from ${19\over2}$ it is possible that there is a combinatorial explanation involving Catalan numbers.

Comment: i don't understand sir :(  can i use permutation and catalan number to get the answer ?