# Question regarding number of non decreasing functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations

I have a question that requires me to find the number of non decreasing functions $f: A \longrightarrow B$ where $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B = \{-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5\}$

I tried doing this by finding the Total number of functions, which according to me is $8^5$. Then, I found the number of decreasing functions to be ${8 \choose 5}$ and there is only one way to order each of those combinations so number of decreasing functions is ${8 \choose 5}$. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

But here's why I don't get the next part, the answer for the number of non decreasing functions isn't $8^5- {8 \choose 5}$

1. I don't get why this is, shouldn't the total number of functions $-$
   number of decreasing functions $=$ number of non-decreasing
   functions? I need a few counter examples to convince me otherwise and I can't seem to be able to come up with one, any help on this/visualizing it would be appreciated.
2. The number of decreasing functions I found to be ${8 \choose 5}$, which isn't asked in the question, just something that I calculated. However, the question also does ask for the number of increasing functions $f:A\longrightarrow B$, and that answer is stated as ${8 \choose 5}$, which makes me question whether my number of decreasing functions is valid. A confirmation here would be highly appreciated too.

Thanks in advance! (I know that there is a similar question from 2015, but since I had some trouble understanding the answers, and also had further questions of my own, I decided to repost rather than posting on a ~6 year old thread)

Here's the link to the old question: [Number of non-decreasing functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396896/number-of-non-decreasing-functions)

Comment: You should at least link the relevant (old) question :)

Comment: @BenjaminWang Ok, editing it in!

Comment: You are wrong in thinking that the sampling is without replacement, which is what $\binom{8}{5}$ represents.  Your query specifies non-decreasing functions rather than strictly increasing functions.  This means that you can have two different elements in the domain map to the same element in the range.  Therefore, the **inelegant** pedestrian approach is to assume that there will be $k$ distinct elements in the range, which receive a map : $k \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}.$  You then have to consider each $k$ separately.  ...see next comment

Comment: Note that if (for example), $k = 3$, that could be represented by **range-values** of either $\{1,1,1,2,3\}$ or $\{1,1,2,2,3\}.$  There may be a more elegant approach, however the approach that I have outlined is **industrial-strength** guaranteed to get the right enumeration.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you mean that $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \longrightarrow {1,1,2,3,3}$ could be a mapping (for example)...is that correct? So when I'm subtracting the number of decreasing functions, shouldn't the answer have those cases in them too? And could you clarify my 2nd point? @user2661923

Comment: My last comment was intended to signify that when $k=3$ (for example) you could have $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \rightarrow \{1,1,2,2,3\}$ or $\{1,1,2,3,3\}$ or $\{1,1,1,2,3\}, to name some examples.

Comment: See my comment to Tan's answer.  I advise against the approach of trying to deduct the number of decreasing functions.

Comment: Turns out a dramatically elegant approach is possible.  See Tan's answer + the comments following his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1$ - "Non-decreasing function" does not mean "A function which is not decreasing". It means $\forall i,j \ \ i>j \implies f(i) \geq f(j) $. So, for example your method counts $(1,3,2,4,5)$ as non-decreasing, but it is not.

$2$ - To find the number of decreasing functions, you just pick $5$ elements and order them in the only possible way (since they have to be decreasing). To find the number of increasing functions, you pick $5$ elements and order them in the only possible way again! That is why the answers are the same.

**Bonus:** To find the number of non-decreasing functions, you have to choose $5$ elements, but this time, repetitions are allowed! So, at the end you are choosing $5$ elements from $8$ elements **with repetitions** and again you order them in the only possible way. It is [clear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))  that you can do this in $\binom{12}{5}$ ways.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120818/discussion-on-answer-by-tan-question-regarding-number-of-non-decreasing-function).

Answer (score 1):

You are interpreting the phrase "non-decreasing function" to mean "a function that is not a decreasing function"; if this were the case, then your answer would be correct. However, the standard definition of a non-decreasing function is a function that is non-strictly increasing, that is, a function $f(x)$ that satisfies $f(x) \le f(y)$ whenever $x<y$. There are more non-decreasing functions than increasing functions—for example, every increasing function is non-decreasing and every constant function is non-decreasing, and there others as well.

It is true, by the way, that the number of (strictly) increasing functions is the same as the number of (strictly) decreasing functions, namely $\binom85$.

Comment: So "non-decreasing" means non-strictly increasing? Okay that helps a bit.... Now my doubt is, if, I subtracted the number of strictly increasing functions from the number of total possible number of functions, why wouldn't I get the number of non-strictly increasing functions? I get a lot more than the answer $792$ What exactly do I get when I perform my method? What are the extra functions that I get but aren't counted as "non-decreasing"?

Comment: That's the same mistake again. "non-strictly increasing" doesn't mean "non (strictly increasing)", but rather "(non strictly) increasing". For example, $f(10)=20,f(11)=20,f(12)=30$ is a non-strictly increasing function; $f(10)=20,f(11)=30,f(12)=25$ is not. Read again the mathematical statement in the fourth line of my answer.

Comment: Ok, so non-strictly increasing means that $f(a) \not \lt f(b) \forall a>b$, Is that right?

Comment: Also, shouldn't a strictly increasing function also satisfy the definition of non decreasing function? Because in a strictly increasing function, we have $f(a)\gt f(b)$ when $a>b$

Comment: Yes and yes to your last two comments!

Answer (score 1):

$(1)$

Total number of functions = decreasing functions $+$ non-decreasing functions $+$ functions that are neither

As an example of the third type, $\{1,4,3,5,2\}$

$(2)$

$8 \choose 5$ is not the number of decreasing functions. It's the number of strictly-decreasing functions.
I am inclined to believe that the textbook answer is wrong because increasing functions can be constant over an interval. The number of strictly-increasing functions is indeed $8 \choose 5$ because there is just one way to arrange them after choosing them.

Go through this link : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function